# Creating proper json from java objects (@Documents) for mongoimport

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Trying to create a file (json) for use by mongoimport utility to populate collections in mongodb to test performance of our application.

I have an existing spring boot application interacting with mongodb.

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Create a Object in Java (say a class annotated with @Document that serves as the entity to persist in a collection)
2. Convert that java object to BSON ===> not sure how to do this
3. Append that to a json file

Thereafter use mongoimport to load the generated file into mongodb.

I have seen that we can use:

```
Map<String, Object> map =
        mapper.convertValue(SOME_JAVA_OBJECT, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
org.bson.Document d = new Document();
d.putAll(map);
String json = d.toJson();
System.out.println(json);
```

However, this JSON has LocaleDate as (this is not what I want):

```
"serviceDate": {"dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY", "dayOfYear": 231, "month": "AUGUST", "nano": 818930000, "year": 2021, "monthValue": 8, "dayOfMonth": 19, "hour": 11, "minute": 57, "second": 5, "chronology": {"id": "ISO", "calendarType": "iso8601"}},
```

What I need is to insert this into Mongo with the date value as:

```
serviceDate: ISODate("2021-08-14T06:37:15.722Z"
```

Essentially using Java to create a json file from existing POJO (@Document instances) for bulk upload using mongoimport utility.

Comment: MongoImport expects JSON, not BSON.

Comment: MongoRestore expects BSON

Comment: @barrypicker: corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a spring boot program, but just a raw driver access program, but this seems to provide eJSON for dates rather than LocalDate...

**File pom.xml**

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test.barry</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                            <finalName>Test</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>test.barry.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**File Main.java**

```
package test.barry;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new com.mongodb.ConnectionString("mongodb://barry:barry@localhost:42011,localhost:42012,localhost:42013/?replicaSet=replSet&retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
                .build();

        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
        
        com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("javatest");
        com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");


        // START WITH A CLEARED OUT EMPTY COLLECTION
        collection.deleteMany(new org.bson.BsonDocument());

        // INSERT A DOCUMENT
        org.bson.Document insertedDocument = new org.bson.Document();
        insertedDocument.append("createdDate", new java.util.Date());
        insertedDocument.append("firstName", "John");
        insertedDocument.append("lastName", "Doe");
        insertedDocument.append("age", 38);
        insertedDocument.append("happinessScore", 95.6);

        java.util.List<org.bson.Document> children = new java.util.ArrayList<org.bson.Document>();
        org.bson.Document child1 = new org.bson.Document();
        child1.append("firstName", "Timmy");
        child1.append("dateOfBirth", new java.util.Date("January 1, 2011"));
        children.add(child1);

        org.bson.Document child2 = new org.bson.Document();
        child2.append("firstName", "Tommy");
        child2.append("dateOfBirth", new java.util.Date("July 1, 2012"));
        children.add(child2);

        org.bson.Document child3 = new org.bson.Document();
        child3.append("firstName", "Tammy");
        child3.append("dateOfBirth", new java.util.Date("November 1, 2013"));
        children.add(child3);

        insertedDocument.append("children", children);

        org.bson.Document spouse = new org.bson.Document();
        spouse.append("firstName", "Jane");
        spouse.append("lastName", "Doe");
        spouse.append("age", 34);

        insertedDocument.append("spouse", spouse);
    
        System.out.println(String.format("Before insert ObjectId: %s", insertedDocument.get("_id")));
        collection.insertOne(insertedDocument);
        System.out.println(String.format("After insert ObjectId: %s", insertedDocument.get("_id")));
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("JSON value is:");
        System.out.println(insertedDocument.toJson());


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // QUERY DOCUMENT
        org.bson.conversions.Bson filter = com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq("_id", insertedDocument.get("_id"));
        org.bson.conversions.Bson sort = com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.ascending("lastName");
        org.bson.conversions.Bson projection = com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.exclude("lastName");

        com.mongodb.client.FindIterable<org.bson.Document> iterable1 = collection.find(filter).sort(sort).skip(0).limit(1).projection(projection);

        // AUTO-CLOSABLE TRY
        try(com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor1 = iterable1.iterator())
        {
            while (cursor1.hasNext())
            {
                org.bson.Document queriedDocument1 = cursor1.next();
                System.out.println(String.format("queriedDocument1: %s", queriedDocument1));
                
                System.out.println("");
                
                System.out.println("JSON value is:");
                System.out.println(insertedDocument.toJson());
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

**Results when Run**

```
Before insert ObjectId: null
15:19:13.672 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"insert": "test", "ordered": true, "writeConcern": {"w": "majority"}, "txnNumber": 1, "$db": "javatest", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1629411546, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "P0qNdQj1rWGa9efu4STXEW4ObCU=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 6966701957889130499}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "kiLR686WT/qOe2yThNehWg==", "subType": "04"}}}, "documents": [{"_id": {"$oid": "611ed8e1a563bc5abdd7957c"}, "createdDate": {"$date": "2021-08-19T22:19:13.628Z"}, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 38, "happinessScore": 95.6, "children": [{"firstName": "Timmy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2011-01-01T08:00:00Z"}}, {"firstName": "Tommy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2012-07-01T07:00:00Z"}}, {"firstName": "Tammy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2013-11-01T07:00:00Z"}}], "spouse": {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 34}}]}' with request id 12 to database javatest on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:1784}] to server localhost:42012
15:19:13.984 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Execution of command with request id 12 completed successfully in 346.59 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:1784}] to server localhost:42012
After insert ObjectId: 611ed8e1a563bc5abdd7957c

JSON value is:
{"createdDate": {"$date": "2021-08-19T22:19:13.628Z"}, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 38, "happinessScore": 95.6, "children": [{"firstName": "Timmy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2011-01-01T08:00:00Z"}}, {"firstName": "Tommy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2012-07-01T07:00:00Z"}}, {"firstName": "Tammy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2013-11-01T07:00:00Z"}}], "spouse": {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 34}, "_id": {"$oid": "611ed8e1a563bc5abdd7957c"}}
15:19:14.005 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"find": "test", "filter": {"_id": {"$oid": "611ed8e1a563bc5abdd7957c"}}, "sort": {"lastName": 1}, "projection": {"lastName": 0}, "limit": 1, "$db": "javatest", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1629411553, "i": 2}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "if1LAHJtpGkJyNjBGcwbpUWXvho=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 6966701957889130499}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "kiLR686WT/qOe2yThNehWg==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 13 to database javatest on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:1784}] to server localhost:42012
15:19:14.006 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Execution of command with request id 13 completed successfully in 4.11 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:1784}] to server localhost:42012
queriedDocument1: Document{{_id=611ed8e1a563bc5abdd7957c, createdDate=Thu Aug 19 15:19:13 PDT 2021, firstName=John, age=38, happinessScore=95.6, children=[Document{{firstName=Timmy, dateOfBirth=Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2011}}, Document{{firstName=Tommy, dateOfBirth=Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 2012}}, Document{{firstName=Tammy, dateOfBirth=Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2013}}], spouse=Document{{firstName=Jane, lastName=Doe, age=34}}}}

JSON value is:
{"createdDate": {"$date": "2021-08-19T22:19:13.628Z"}, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 38, "happinessScore": 95.6, "children": [{"firstName": "Timmy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2011-01-01T08:00:00Z"}}, {"firstName": "Tommy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2012-07-01T07:00:00Z"}}, {"firstName": "Tammy", "dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2013-11-01T07:00:00Z"}}], "spouse": {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 34}, "_id": {"$oid": "611ed8e1a563bc5abdd7957c"}}
```